# Ruby attr_accessor with method name != instance variable name

Tags: ruby, instance-variables, attr-accessor

Is there a short way to do this?

```
def value
   @val
end

def value=(value)
    @val = value
end
```

Comment: Why do you care about instance var name?

Comment: Because I'm subclassing and. "If a subclass uses an instance variable with the same name as a variable used by one of its ancestors, it will overwrite the value of its ancestor’s variable".

Comment: And does the superclass have getter and setter for that ivar?

Comment: Yes, it has `attr_accessor :value`.

Comment: And you want to redefine accessors, but leave ivars separate. Why? Do you want to access both ivars?

Comment: The problem is that a method of the superclass uses the internal `@value` that sometimes is uncorrectly set by the subclass. In particular in the superclass `@value` is a String, in subclass is a boolean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is not. All attr_accessor does is define two methods, one called value (in this case) and the other called value= that set an instance variable of the same name. Since you should only be accessing the instance variable via the getter/setter methods, it shouldn't matter what it is called internally.

If you are inheriting, you can use a call to super to ensure constancy:

```
class Walrus
  attr_accessor :bubbles
end

class Harold < Walrus
  def bubbles
    # do Harold related things here
    super
  end

  def bubbles=(value)
    # do Harold related things here
    super(value)
  end
end
```

EDIT

If you really want to do it then you can define your own method on Class:

```
class Class
  def attr_accessor2(method_name, attribute_name)
    define_method(method_name) do
      instance_variable_get("@#{attribute_name}")
    end

    define_method("#{method_name}=") do |value|
      instance_variable_set("@#{attribute_name}", value)
    end
  end
end
```

I haven't tested it, but something like that should work. I'm not saying it's a good idea, but that is what you're looking for.

EDIT2

Here is how it works in practice:

```
1.9.3p0 :012 > class Derp
1.9.3p0 :013?>   attr_accessor2 :herp, :meep
1.9.3p0 :014?>   end
 => #<Proc:0x007fc75b02e958@(irb):7 (lambda)> 
1.9.3p0 :015 > d = Derp.new
 => #<Derp:0x007fc75b027e00> 
1.9.3p0 :016 > d.herp
 => nil 
1.9.3p0 :017 > d.herp = 10
 => 10 
1.9.3p0 :018 > d.herp
 => 10 
1.9.3p0 :019 > d.instance_variable_get("@meep")
 => 10
```

Comment: The problem is that the subclass uses an instance variable with the same name as a variable used by one of its ancestors, so the value of its ancestor’s variable in overwrited. But this is not done intentionally, leading me to a bug. Some I'm using accessors.

Comment: If you want access to the superclass' variables then you cannot overwrite them. That means naming your inherited class' instance variables something else. The methods I wrote in Harold won't touch @bubbles unless you tell them too, that way they won't overwrite the data in Walrus.

Comment: Anyway, is there a way to do it? Like `attr_accessor :value for(@val)

Comment: I added what you're looking for. Ruby allows you to open up any class, including Class, so you can just define it yourself. Not necessarily a good idea in terms of readability, though.

Comment: @user1449165 I added an example of how that would work in practice.

Answer (score 0):

```
attr_accessor :val
alias_method :value, :val
alias_method :value=,:val=
```

If you want to block the access of the original method, you can use

```
remove_method :val
remove_method :val=
```

I don't know if you consider this shorter.

Comment: Well, not bad, mine:6 lines yours: 5 lines you won! ;-) Thanks.